# How to detect and filter peaks over time series data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I have a pandas dataframe of user logins like this:

```
    id     datetime_login 
    646  2017-03-15 15:30:25
    611  2017-04-14 11:38:30
    611  2017-05-15 08:49:01
    651  2017-03-15 15:30:25
    611  2017-03-15 15:30:25
    652  2017-03-08 14:03:56
    652  2017-03-08 14:03:56
    652  2017-03-15 15:30:25
    654  2017-03-15 15:30:25
    649  2017-03-15 15:30:25
    902  2017-09-09 15:00:00
    902  2017-02-13 16:39:53
    902  2017-11-15 12:00:00
    902  2017-11-15 12:00:00
    902  2017-09-09 15:00:00
    902  2017-05-15 08:48:47
    902  2017-11-15 12:00:00
```

After plotting the logins:

```
df.datetime_login = df.datetime_login.apply(lambda x: str(x)[:10])
df.datetime_login = df.datetime_login.apply(lambda x: date(int(x[:4]), int(x[5:7]), int(x[8:10])))


fig, ax = subplots()
df.datetime_login.value_counts().sort_index().plot(figsize=(25,10), colormap='jet',fontsize=20)
```

1. How can I detect in my plot the peaks in the time series data?
2. How can I filter into an array the peaks in my time series data?

I tried to:

```
import peakutils
indices = peakutils.indexes(df, thres=0.4, min_dist=1000)
print(indices)
```

However, I got:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'int'
```

However, I got:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where 
`df.datetime_login.value_counts().sort_index().plot(figsize=(25,10), colormap='jet',fontsize=20)` plots:

[image]

Let's try the following, you need to use the series returned by `value_counts` instead of your original df, `peakutils.indexes`:

```
df_counts = df.datetime_login.value_counts().sort_index()
df_counts[peakutils.indexes(df_counts, thres=0.4, min_dist=1000)]
```

Output:

```
2017-03-15 15:30:25    6
Name: datetime_login, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks for the help but its just returning me one peak... is there any way of returning all the peaks?